Почему один раз моргает экран при старте системы Linux Mint?
У меня проблема с тем, что когда я запускаю систему где надо ввести пароль у меня через несколько секунд один раз моргает экран, а потом когда я ввожу пароль и захожу в систему у меня снова через несколько секунд появляется экран и опять один раз моргает. Я попробовал зайти с помощью флага nomodeset и тогда проблема исчезла, но как вы понимаете это разовое решение. Думаю, дело в драйверах.
КОМАНДА inxi -G:
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Quanta HD User Facing driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast platforms: x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

СИСТЕМА:
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 11.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin
    vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A315-58 v: V1.26
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: TGL model: Camellia_TL v: V1.26
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Insyde v: 1.26
    date: 03/14/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 27.1 Wh (100.0%)
    condition: 27.1/37.0 Wh (73.0%) volts: 8.6 min: 7.7
    model: PANASONIC AP16M5J type: Li-ion serial: <filter>
    status: Full cycles: 48
Memory:
  RAM: total: 7.53 GiB used: 2.74 GiB (36.3%)
  RAM Report:
    permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64
    type: MT MCP smt: enabled arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache:
    L1: 320 KiB L2: 5 MiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 756 high: 1060 min/max: 400/4200 cores:
    1: 464 2: 920 3: 717 4: 740 5: 668 6: 1060 7: 962 8: 523
    bogomips: 38707
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
    active: eDP-1 empty: HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:9a49 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Quanta HD User Facing type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-8:2 chip-ID: 0408:a061 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
    s-size: 508x285mm (20.0x11.2") s-diag: 582mm (22.9")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 142
    size: 344x194mm (13.5x7.6") diag: 395mm (15.5") modes: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa
    24.2~git2405230600.2abdc8~oibaf~j (git-2abdc84 2024-05-23
    jammy-oibaf-ppa)
    compat-v: 4.6 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8 class-ID: 0401
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-107-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0f0 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
    type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-10:3 chip-ID: 8087:0aaa
    class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 3 state: up
    address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1 sub-v: 20ce hci-v: 5.1
    rev: 20ce
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 31.87 GiB (14.3%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37240G
    size: 223.57 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter>
    rev: 0010 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 29.36 GiB used: 25.18 GiB (85.8%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 33.6 MiB (35.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-3: /home size: 21.85 GiB used: 6.65 GiB (30.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda7
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 7.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/sda6
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2877 apt: 2858 flatpak: 19
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/mssql-server-2019 bionic main
    2: deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022 focal main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
    1: deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ppa-jammy.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/deadsnakes-ppa-jammy.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com virginia main upstream import backport
    2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-jammy.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/oibaf-graphics-drivers-jammy.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list
    1: deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt virginia-pgdg main
Info:
  Processes: 326 Uptime: 2h 27m wakeups: 3885 Init: systemd v: 249
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13

